# Visual Studio 2017 equivalent for Eclipse Quick outline (Ctrl + O)

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ide

In Eclipse there is `Ctrl + O` shortcut for quick outline, which lets explore class attributes and methods with incremental search

[image]

Is there equivalent shortcut in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Dude, that's Visual Studio Code, not VS 2017...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need a `Class Veiw` (from `View` or `Ctrl+Shift+C`). Or the bar at top of edit window.

Or,

[image]

Basically you don't need shortcuts. After you type  the dot this list drop automatically. But `Ctrl+Space` do the same.

Also, you can open a definition in the 'Peak View', by `Ctrl + click`:
[image]

Or open `Code definition window` (from `View` or `Ctrl+Shift+V`)

Comment: Class View still needs mouse to access the input... I'm not interested about instance methods, but the class method of current class in editor. I'm surprised there's not feature as Eclipses quick outline, which is one of my most used shortcuts

Comment: If you don't like using mouse, try to find a suitable plugin for VS, such as VsVim or something with the Eclipse tag

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard command you want is `Window.MovetoNavigationBar` as can be seen in [Default keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio). Its shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, though in Visual Studio / Tools / Options it's asociated with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>. Both work for me.

Once in Navigation Bar, you actually have three separate combo-boxes between which you can navigate using <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. The third one is the Eclipse Outline lookalike.

Unfortunately, it's easier to do this via mouse, as there is no direct shortcut to the last combo-box.

Comment: I hope there's something more convenient

Answer (score 0):

You can use Go To Members option using (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>) shortcut. If it is listing all the members across the project,  you may want to scope it to current document (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)

[image: Member Outline Search in Visual Studio]